# commenting in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

How can I comment multiple lines in spark-sql

%sql

```
/*
    select * from database.tablename 
    where condition
*/
```

gives me the following error

```
Error in SQL statement: 

    ParseException: 
    mismatched input '/' expecting {'(', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'OPTIMIZE', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 1, pos 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single line comment we should use `--` and for multiline `/* comments`  */`.`

Actually comment is working in your case, problem is - spark ignores those comments after that it looks for sql commands but you didn't specify any.

screenshot from databricks

[image: screenshot from databricks]

Below code will throw error.

```
  spark.sql(
    """
      | /* comment..1
      | comment..2 */
      |""")
    .show()
```

but this works perfectly, since spark got the actual sql command to process.

```
  spark.sql(
    """
      | /* comment..1
      | comment..2 */
      | select current_date
      |""")
    .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**couldn't test it:**

```
 /* This should be a comment
     over multiple lines */
```

**EDIT:**
If this doesn't work, try:

```
/** Definitely a multilined
*    comment 
*/
```

Comment: What exactly are you writing? Just the comment or something else before?

Comment: just the comment , but there's a magic command %sql in the beginning.. Its like this.. %sql /* query */

Comment: try it once without the command(just cut it with ctrl+x, you can insert it after, again with ctrl+v) and see if the same error still exists.
Second Comment-Command got updated.

Comment: tried second command with and without magic command, but same error. is this working for you in databricks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%%sql

SELECT 1
/*
your peace of code here

*/;
```

the key point is the semicolon.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the parser (although it could also be an intentional 'limitation').  I am using DBR 12.2 LTS (Apache Spark 3.3.2), and this magic works:

```
%sql
```

and so does this one:

```
%sql
-- Hello
```

Meaning that empty SQL is okay.  This does not work:

```
%sql
/* Hello */
```

It says this:

> [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near end of input.(line 1, pos
> 11)
>
> == SQL == /* Hello */
> -----------^^^

But, any valid sql expression after the multiline comment succeeds:

```
%sql
/* Hello */
select 1
```

My guess is that their parser grammar defines a multiline comment with a trailing sql expression so it considers the input incomplete.  I am sure this will never change so the answer is not to end a sql cell with a multiline comment and don't use a multiline comment to disable an entire sql command (that's how I got here)

UPDATE:
I believe this was a bug since this is fixed in DBR 13.2 (Apache Spark 3.4.0)